# Mold in storage

Tags: food-safety, food-preservation, fermentation, mold

I've been making my own saurkraut for about 2 years - with 1.5-2% as per the recipe that came with my crock.  Today I noticed that two full, as yet unopened jars in the refrigerator both have a kind of mold growing in the top of the kraut. I've never seen this before. Is it bad? Its legs are going to be a long way down, right? [image: ,]

Answer (score 5):

Well, Sandor Ellix Katz writes in [The Art of Fermentation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/160358286X) that some mould on the top is not a problem, you can scrape it away. But for me, this seems too much, **I would not eat it**.

From what I see on your picture, your problem might be, that the kraut is not covered with liquid. For fermentation you need anaerobic conditions, meaning that the kraut is not on the air, it is fully covered with brine. Mould needs aerobic conditions, meaning it grows where the kraut is on air. Try to make sure the brine covers your kraut the next time you making it again.

Comment: Agreed...when I first saw that photo, my heart just about stopped. :-) Not enough brine and too much mold. Definitely a start-over moment.

Answer (score 0):

This will raise the pH and cause a potential for botulism growth if you stored them >36F.  I do this stuff for a living so toss them please. Some mold on the top of a fermentation vat is normal in the jar is not normal. As stated above I think you need to put more liquid in the jars and less product next time.